# how to transfer the control during success: of jquery to html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using following jquery statements to validate the user details.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Login",
        data:'uname='+encodeURIComponent(uname)+'&'+'pass='+encodeURIComponent(pass),
        dataType: "json",

        //if received a response from the server
        success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
             if(data==true)
             {
                 $("#error").show(1500).css({visibility: "visible"});
                  $("#error").append("<b>success!</b>");
              }
```

but i nee to transfer the control to other html page during success.

```
$("#error").show(1500).css({visibility: "visible"});
$("#error").append("<b>success!</b>");
```

I'm trying to change the above statements to transfer the control. Please anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: what does "transfer control" mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "transfer the control to other html page"?  The two statements change the display of an element and append some content to that element.  Is this not working?

Comment: "transfer the control" you mean the focus? And you mean another html element, not html page?

Comment: I mean. I need to load other html page.For example:If I'm in index.html page.And when i click on submit button i need to validate the data, Then i need to load index1.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

within your successful login condition use:

```
window.location ='index1.html'; 
/* or whatever url you want and make sure path is correct relative to page or use absolute url */
```

This tells browser to open that url using javascript